# Why does 'feliĉe' mean "unfortunately" whilst 'feliĉa' means "happy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

The dictionary is Esperanto-English Dictionary [1](https://www.esperanto-panorama.net/vortaro/eoen.htm).
[image: Feliĉe is Unforatunately in Dictionary]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That dictionary contains an error. Search the word "malfeliĉe" in that dictionary, it's translated by the same word "unfortunately".

Comment: Dankon! I rely on this dictionary quite a lot, it's really confusing when it shows me incorrect words.

Answer (score -6):

Gjrnerale fortunately estus la traduko de "felicze", sed en la angla tiu vorto, qvankam logika, pli rara estas,; precipe kun iom negativa tono ankaû en Esperanto preferatus diri " senfelicze" tiukaze, au ecz "misfelicze" ; au se ironie, tiam transfelicze, resp.  "hofeliczege".